# Read contacts not working

Tags: android

My app can read contacts from tablet ok, but can not read from phone device, so what is the reason? and my app using `'ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI'` to read contacts to **VCard** format. I have `read/write permission in manifest file`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Code, logs, anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);

    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
      String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
      String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


    }



    phones.close();
 }
```

use this code for read all contact.